# Modified local EF Core Entity still fetched by a new query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Lets consider these two entity classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int? TeacherId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Teacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And lets consider this `Entity Framework Core` scenario:

```
var studentSet = dbContext.Set<Student>();

// Get a student
var specialStudent = await studentSet.FindAsync(42);

// Exclude it from the relationship
specialStudent.TeacherId = null;

// Get all the remaining student in the relation ship
var assignedStudents = await studentSet.Where(s => s.TeacherId != null).ToListAsync();

// Do some modifications on assigned students

// Only at the very end of the scenario: commit all the changes to the database in one call
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

My issue is that my `specialStudent` is part of the `assignedStudents`, even if its `TeacherId` is null as expected.

I guessed that Entity Framework Core would run the query on the database, compare the results with its cached entities, fetch the missing one, and kind of re-run the query to exclude from the results the modified entities that does not fit the query.

I guess the last part of my guessing was wrong.

**Is it possible to achieve what I want?**

I don't know if it is relevant am using `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` in version `3.1.4` and my DbContext is configured to use Proxy (`optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`).

Comment: 1) you never saved the changes. `I guessed that Entity Framework Core would run the query on the database,` it will, along with any other change when you call `SaveChanges`. 2) There's no reason to use `.Set<Student>()`. The entities are supposed to be configured in the DbContext itself and available as `DbSet<>` properties. You can't even use `Set<>` without configuring the entities first, so why use `dbContext.Set<Student>()` instead of `dbContext.Students` ? This doesn't make your code more dynamic

Comment: PS: You don't set `Teacher` to null either

Comment: 1) That's right, I did not save the changes YET. This step comes later in the scenario, to commit all the changes at once (to act like a transaction). But you probably hit the point here. I will give it a try with an overall `Transaction` and a local `SaveChanges`. 2) For brevity sake, I omit the DbContext configuration. Obviously, my entities are configured within the DbContext, and I put the `dbContext.Set<Student>()` here just for the exemple. 3) True, I don't set the `Student.Teacher` navigation property to null. Since the foreign key property is set, I thought it was not necessary.

Comment: `I will give it a try with an overall Transaction and a local SaveChanges` don't do that. That breaks EF's way of working. EF isn't broken. There's no Foreign Key property, the actual relation is the `Teacher` property, not `TeacherID`. Post a *complete*, minimal example that actually demonstrates your problem

Comment: In this case, how do you perform several operations like I need, with a single "commit to database" action?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: My example is complete. I remove an entity from a relationship. Then I perform a query that is not supposed to return that entity anymore (because of the previous modification). But the query still return that entity (I guess because in the database, the relationship still exists). The problem is I need to "push" the changes to the database in one call, at the very end of my scenario.

Comment: The examples in [Managing One To Many Relationships With Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships/managing-one-to-many-relationships) are mostly complete, although they omit the actual class definitions. Check [Removing Relations](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships/managing-one-to-many-relationships#removing-relationships) section. Each example is 4-5 lines, requiring no guesses

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I edited the question a long time ago to add the `SaveChanges` BUT, the issue is NOT with the `SaveChanges`. It is with the query returning an entity that is not anymore in the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand why Panagiotis Kanavos said in the comments that I should NOT do this. The transactions exist for this purpose and Entity Framework let us use it very easily. I can't see why it would `break EF's way of working`.

This is why I will not mark this as the accepted answer right away, so he/someone else can explain why it is bad. But in the meantime , this did the job for me:

```
// Initialize the transaction
await dDbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

var studentSet = dbContext.Set<Student>();

// Get a student
var specialStudent = await studentSet.FindAsync(42);

// Exclude it from the relationship
specialStudent.TeacherId = null;

// Apply the changes locally so it can be reflected in the next calls 
// Since there is a transaction "in progress", the changes are not commited to the database
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

// Get all the remaining student in the relationship
// This time, mySpecialStudent is no longer part of the results
var assignedStudents = await studentSet.Where(s => s.TeacherId != null).ToListAsync();

// Do some modifications on assigned students

// Save the changes to thoses entities
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

// Only at the very end of the scenario commit the transaction to push the data to the database
await dbContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.CommitAsync();
```

Comment: Has your solution held up?

Comment: Never let me down for now.

Answer (score 0):

In other to use your algoritm you have use a Transaction ( only if you need to assign TeacherId to null and modified another students in the same time) and a call SaveChanges after each step. Also you will have to mark EntityState.Modified each modified record (or property), otherwise it will not be saved to DB.

Why you don't use this?

```
var assignedStudents = await dbContext.Students.Where(s => s.Id !=42 ) .ToListAsync();
// Do some modifications on assigned students
var specialStudent =  await dbContext.Students.Where(s => s.Id ==42 ) 
specialStudent.TeacherId = null;
dbContext.Entry(specialStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the scenario I described in the question is just a minimal, reproducible example. The actual situation is much more complex and involve different layers. It is not that simple and I cannot just refactor the code. But I am currently trying to use a `Transaction` and several `SaveChanges` as you suggest.

Comment: A transaction is **not** necessary at all. `SaveChanges` uses an internal transaction to persist all changes. ` a call SaveChanges after each step` that's just wrong and breaks EF's way of working and wastes both its disconnected operation *and* the built-in Unit-of-Work behavior. Because it breaks EF, an explicit transaction is needed again. Because of that, a long-lived connection is required, increasing concurrency conflicts and harming performance and scaleability.  EF itself isn't broken.

Comment: It is in my case since I only want the last call to SaveChanges to actually updates the database.

Comment: Yes, if it is not important to have TeacherId is null and modifications together than you don't need a transaction in this case.

Comment: To @Panagiotis Kanavos: You have to read everything before to vote down. It is not clear from the question if it should be in one transaction or not. I mentioned the safest way. In my code there is no any transactions and it doesn't need any multiple save changes.

Comment: I edit the question to reflect that I need to "commit" the changes to the database in one call, at the very end.